# Как перебрать вложенный объект?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, объекты

Я получаю вложенный объект из API в своем приложении на Vue JS.
Отввет от сервера выглядит следующим образом:

[image: Ответ от сервера]

Я пытаюсь разложить это в двухуровневый выпадающий список, где на первом уровне идет название отдела NameOtdel, а на втором список подотделов NamePodrazdel

Вот мой код в шаблоне vue

```
<div class="row">
                  <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <select class="group-select" ref="select2" v-model="depart_select">
                      <optgroup v-for="(department,index) in departments" :key="index" :label="department.NameOtdel">
                        <option  :value="department.NamePodrazdel">{{ department.NamePodrazdel }} </option>
                      </optgroup>
                    </select>
                    <label>Структурное подразделение</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

В Postman ответ от сервера имеет такой вид

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так а в чем собственно проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю вы хотели отображать раздел и подразделы в селекте.
В этом случае вам необходимо было перебрать ещё массив подразделов, чтобы селект заработал так, как необходимо

[Пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-https-ftdue?file=/src/App.vue)